# How are images and generic types best handled in network programming

Tags: c#, network-programming

I have a application which sends commands to a smartphone (running a server) via LAN and receives results.
Currently for the data transfer I have the following two classes:

**NetworkMessage**: Introduces some form of simple protocol where the header is simple an integer with the length of the message:

```
public class NetworkMessage
{
    public byte[] EncodedMessageHeader { get; set; }
    public byte[] EncodedMessageBody { get; set; }

    public NetworkMessage(byte[] _encodedBody, byte[] _encodedHeader = null)
    {
        EncodedMessageBody = _encodedBody;
        if(_encodedHeader == null)
        {
            EncodedMessageHeader = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(EncodedMessageBody.Length));
        }
        else
        {
            EncodedMessageHeader = _encodedHeader;
        }
    }

    public NetworkMessage(NetworkCommandModel command)
    {
        var decodedMessageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command); 
        Encode(decodedMessageBody);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the encoded message from the decoded one
    /// </summary>
    private  void Encode(string decodedMessageBody)
    {
        EncodedMessageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decodedMessageBody);
        EncodedMessageHeader = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(EncodedMessageBody.Length));
    }

    public NetworkCommandModel GetCommand()
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NetworkCommandModel>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(EncodedMessageBody));
    }
}
```

**NetworkCommandModel**: A simple Model telling me the type of command and it's parameters (=payload)

```
public class NetworkCommandModel
{
    #region Public Properties
    public NetworkCommandTypeEnum CommandType { get; set; }
    public string CommandPayload { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public NetworkCommandModel() {}

    public NetworkCommandModel(NetworkCommandTypeEnum _commandType, string CommandPayLoad)
    {
        CommandType = _commandType;
        CommandPayload = CommandPayLoad;
    }
    #endregion

}
```

This works fine so far as long is the payload stays a simple string. However, what if my payload is an object - an instance of a custom class - or an image?

For general types I could make the property for the payload into a generic: `public T CommandPayload { get; set; }`. It would need a bit of refactoring but I suppose it could work. But if the payload is an image, I don't think it is a good thing to serialize and deserialize it with json.

How, would one handle such a case?

Comment: Are you looking for something **more efficient?**  You could try [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/) or [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'll have to read into it, but are you saying, that If I use for example BSON as serializer, I could use the CommandPayLoad as generic type and pass in some image class instance and still be efficient?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: Hmm, that would be awesome, since BSON is already implemented in the Newtonsoft Library I'm currently using.

Comment: Try [Zyan Communication Framework](https://github.com/zyanfx/Zyan), works on .NET, Mono and Xamarin.Android.